# Changing values of pointers

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I have an object like this:

```
Node<T> *s = object;
setLength(&s);

void setLength(Node<T> *temp)
{  ..... }
```

This does not seem to change value of s. How do I modify s?

Comment: Show us the actual code in `setLength`.

Comment: all it has is:

temp->left = temp->left->right;

Comment: Well, what are the values of `left` and `left->right` before and after calling the function?

Comment: left is a pointer right is also a pointer

Comment: And what are the values of those pointers?

Comment: And what are those integer values? 0x0ff45? 0x00000? 0xffaa89?

Answer (score 0):

Your code as given has a syntax error. It probably should be:

```
void setLength(Node<T> *temp) { ... }

Node<T> *s = object;
setLength(s);
```